# Cannot find module 'agentkeepalive' when updating NPM to 7.20.3

Tags: node.js, npm, nvm

When I'm trying to update npm to **7.20.3** (`npm install -g npm@7.20.3`), npm throws :

```
npm ERR! code MODULE_NOT_FOUND
npm ERR! Cannot find module 'agentkeepalive'
npm ERR! Require stack:
npm ERR! - /Users/ShaggyRogers/.nvm/versions/node/v14.16.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/make-fetch-happen/agent.js
...
```

Answer (score 133, accepted):

In order to quickly fix this error just install or re-install globally `agentkeepalive` :

```
npm install -g agentkeepalive --save
```

Then update npm :

```
npm install -g npm@7.20.3
```

**UPDATE** :

Since June 23 2021, the bug seems to be fixed in `v7.17.0` ([GitHub issue](https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/2818#issuecomment-867131507))

You can first upgrade to `v7.17.0`:

```
npm install -g npm@7.17.0
```

Then upgrade to the last version of npm :

```
npm install -g npm@7.21.0
```

or

```
npm install -g npm@latest
```

Comment: This does seem to work but it would be helpful if you added some explanation of why this is necessary, or a link to an applicable bug report where it is discussed.

Comment: Can you detail your problem ?

Comment: Thanks for your help! It worked fine for me

Comment: The updated part worked well for me, coming from 7.5.4 -> 8.5.5

Comment: I'm still seeing the same error when trying to upgrade from 7.10.0 to 7.17.0. So the update fix might not work for everyone.

Comment: current latest version as of this comment is 9.1.3 you can simply use the last command in the update as in original comment

Answer (score 1):

This has been discussed [on github](https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/2818)

TL;DR;

It has been fixed in npm v7.17.0 and newer. I managed to upgrade from 7.10.0 to 7.21.0 and avoid this error entirely (and not dealing with  **agentkeepalive**) by upgrading first to 7.17.0 and then to 7.21.0.

Comment: I tried that but it didn't work. 
   Aviator@AW:/mnt/c/Users/Adrian$ npm install -g npm@7.17.0
   npm ERR! code MODULE_NOT_FOUND
   npm ERR! Cannot find module 'agentkeepalive'

Installing agentkeepalive worked though.

Comment: Maybe the "right" way is just to uninstall (https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/using-npm/removal) and then install the latest.

Comment: It appears to be back when upgrading from 7.13.0 to 8.1.3

Comment: It's not surprising, as 7.13.0 is older than 7.17.0

Answer (score 0):

I do not know how, but this one worked for me:

```
$ npm --version
7.8.0
$ sudo npm uninstall -g npm

removed 252 packages, and audited 1 package in 586ms

found 0 vulnerabilities
$ sudo npm install -g npm

added 1 package, and audited 206 packages in 1s

11 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities
$ npm --version
8.17.0
```

Posting it as the accepted answer has not helped.