# azure function app console - npm install doesn't work. Couldn't install agentkeepalive

Tags: azure, azure-functions, npm-install

I need to install **agentkeepalive** in azure functions. I was able to install other packages an hour ago. But as soon as I tried to install agentkeepalive, it doesn't honour any npm install command nor return any error messages in the console.

I tried this [Cannot find module 'agentkeepalive' when updating NPM to 7.20.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68618743/cannot-find-module-agentkeepalive-when-updating-npm-to-7-20-3) it is not working.

I restarted the azure function app and tried to install the package, no luck. Now I couldn't install any package.
Help in installing the packages from this console. Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the node.js version in the azure portal and it started working. I think it just hung somewhere. Changing the version re-enabled or caused node.js restart. Here's the image attached.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

**In the Azure App Service Editor**, the latest version will be `6.14.*` because in app services the latest node version is 14v and the node.js 14 LTS npm latest version is `6.14.*`. So though you try installing the latest version the npm still remains `6.14.*`.

[image]

To install the `npm install -g npm@7.20.3`, it needs more than `{"node":">= 8.0.0"}`.

For doing that you need to update few settings from the `Azure portal >` `<your-function-app> >`  `configuration` > `settings` tab from left pane. Below are the settings :

```yaml
Name : `WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION`
Value : 14.15.0

Name : `WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE`
Value : 0 [If published functions already]

Name : `FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION`
Value : beta [optional]
```

[image]

Even if you update npm to the latest version, it will stay to the last version release i.e., `6.14.*`
Also, try changing your node version in your Azure App service for getting compatible error-free npm versions upgrade.

Below are the references for the NPM-Node Compatibility release versions to Azure App Services (Editor - Preview).

**REFERENCES :**

1. [Azure Functions Support for node.JS 14 and .Net 5 Is Generally Available](https://www.infoq.com/news/2021/03/azure-functions-dotnet5-nodejs14/).
2. [Node.js version 12.14.x be available on Azure App Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/5483/when-will-nodejs-version-1214x-be-available-on-azu.html).

Comment: Thanks, I tried this  but it didn't work in my case.

Comment: If the posted answer helped, you may mark it as the answer by clicking the check mark. Doing so can help other community members